# Creating Custom WMI classes for SCCM queries

Tags: wmi, sccm

I am working to create a custom WMI class for use with SCCM's device collection membership query rules to expose some organization specific information to SCCM for collection creation. I have managed to add a new class in with the MOF file below, and it shows up in the GUI as expected with the desired display name.

The only issue I believe I have left to solve is how to make the generated query work as expected. I know by default joins are not supported in WQL. However Microsoft seems to be using them regularly in these queries, and I have verified they work as expected outside of the application. Is there some sort of joining class I need to create to make this work? Is there some attribute to designate a property as a forigen key??

I have searched through the System Center Configuration Manager SDK documentation, and the WMI reference on the Windows Dev Center site for a few hours without much luck and would really appreciate any helpful input.

**MOF File:**

```
#pragma namespace ("\\\\.\\root\\sms\\site_lab")
[DisplayName("CMDB CI Computer")]
class SMS_G_System_MTS_cmdb_ci_computer : SMS_G_System    
{
    [key] uint32 ResourceID;
    string asset_tag;
    string dv_company;
    string dv_cost_center;
    string dv_location;
};
```

**SCCM Generated Query:**

```
select * from  SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_MTS_cmdb_ci_computer on SMS_G_System_MTS_cmdb_ci_computer.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
```

I am testing these commands with the Get-CimInstance command in powershell with the below results

**Powershell:**

This command returns the joined objects as expected.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root\sms\site_lab' -Query 'select SMS_G_System_PROCESSOR.Architecture from  SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_PROCESSOR on SMS_G_System_PROCESSOR.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId'
```

This command throws an "Invalid Query" Error.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root\sms\site_lab' -Query 'select asset_tag from  SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_MTS_cmdb_ci_computer on SMS_G_System_MTS_cmdb_ci_computer.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId'
```

Comment: Is your problem that the join does not work at all or that the result is one column per table where the information is not displayed anymore but instead something like BaseManagementObjects are listed (also you have a trailing ' in your generated query but I assume this is only a copy and paste artifact)? Also how do you execute the query? Finally I assume it is not possible to do your query in sql on the db directly, because I would allways suggest this method whenever possible (but sometimes it isn't)

Comment: The query does not work at all i receive an "Invalid query" error when i run it. I am executing the query with the below powershell command directly on the management server.
`Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root\sms\site_lab' -Query 'select * from  SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_MTS_cmdb_ci_computer on SMS_G_System_MTS_cmdb_ci_computer.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId'`

Comment: Ok powershell is good because you will probably get the basemanagement thing once it works and i think powershell can work around that. I have not a lot experience with the mof extensions but I have one custom class in my environment and I can perform an inner join so it should be possible. I created it with the RegKeyToMof tool years ago so I am far from an expert but one thing I noticed is that if I export my mof again is that my custom class seems to derive from "class customclass : SMS_Class_Template" and not g_system like in your example. Maybe this could be a hint?